# Trying to Find Photos on Harddrive from Photos App

Tags: applications, photos

Our hard drive died and we had to get a new one - I have my old hard drive in one of those NexStar things (bear with me as I am not that good at computers!).  I am looking for my photos from the Photo App and I can't seem to find them anywhere on the old hard drive to import onto our new hard drive.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

### Finding the Library

Pictures from photos are usually in a single big archive called `Photos Library` found in a user's `Pictures` folder. Go to the root of your hard drive (the root is what you see when you open it, before opening any folders inside it), and then open the following directories:

```
Users > (your user name) > Pictures
```

The library should be there.

### Opening the Library

To open it, open Photos. The icon usually bounces into its place the Dock while Photos is loading the pictures, and then the window shows up. You will want to hold the <kbd>option</kbd> key before the window shows up (I usually do this by holding the <kbd>option</kbd> key when I click on the Photos icon). This will tell Photos you want to open another library, so instead of showing you the usual Photos window, it will open something like this:

[image: Choose Library Window]

Click on that `Open Library...` button and find your old library as described above.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is most likely too late to be of use to you but I thought others in your situation might benefit from the information. The Photos application stores your movies and images inside a single database file that is located in the Pictures folder.

`/User/YOUR_USERNAME/Pictures/Photos Library.photolibrary`

To get to your data you need to right-click on `Photos Library.photolibrary`, choose `"Show Package Contents"`, and then look in the following locations:

Images:

> /User/YOUR_USERNAME/Pictures/Photos 
>   Library.photolibrary/resources/media/version

Video:

> /User/YOUR_USERNAME/Pictures/Photos
>   Library.photolibrary/resources/media/master

Hope this helps!